# $(1-x^2)y''-xy'+\lambda y=0$ -Sturm–Liouville

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I try to get this equation in Sturm–Liouville and I get stuck.

$(1-x^2)y''-xy'+\lambda y=0$

My solution:

$\mu(1-x^2)y''-\mu xy'+\mu \lambda y=(py')'+(\lambda r-q)y$

$\mu(1-x^2)y''-\mu xy'+\mu \lambda y=p'y'+py''+(\lambda r-q)y$

$p'=\mu x, p=\mu(1-x^2) \implies \frac{p'}{p}=\frac{x}{1-x^2}\implies ln(p)=-\frac{1}{2}ln|1-x^2|\implies p=\frac{1}{\sqrt{(|1-x^2|)}}$

Then $\mu=\frac{1}{(1-x^2)^3}$

$\frac{1}{(1-x^2)^2}y''-\frac{1}{(1-x^2)^3}xy'+\frac{1}{(1-x^2)^3}\lambda y=p'y'+py''+(\lambda r-q)y$

Here I get stuck ,please help

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, denote

$$P(x)=1-x^2\;,\;\;Q(x)=-x\implies e^{\int\frac QPdx}=e^{\frac12\int\frac{-2x}{1-x^2}dx}=e^{\log|1-x^2|^{1/2}}=\sqrt{1-x^2}$$

so your integration factor (this could in fact better be called The S-L factor...) is

$$\frac1Pe^{\int\frac QPdx}=\frac1{1-x^2}\sqrt{1-x^2}=(1-x^2)^{-1/2}$$

Multiply now the whole diff. equation by it and get:

$$\sqrt{1-x^2}\,y''-\frac x{\sqrt{1-x^2}}y'+\lambda\frac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}}y=0\iff$$

$$\left((1-x^2)^{1/2}y'\right)'+\lambda\sqrt{1-x^2}\,y=0$$

and there you have your diff. eq. in Sturm-Liouville normal form.

Comment: Thanks ' I can't see what is wrong with my solution, I checked it a lot of times and still don't get why my S-L factor is different than yours.

Comment: @erez Well, because you did something different...and didn't pay attention to the sign of $\;p=-\mu x\;$ ...!